# Selecting Divs in Table that Contain Numbers w/ Mouse and Summing Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a table with each td tag in it containing one div tag that contains a number in its innerHTML.  As a user holds down the left mouse button and drags across the numbers to select them, I would like to update a label in the document with the sum of the numbers as they're being selected.  I figure this should be pretty straight forward, but after searching everywhere, I can't figure out how to do this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<table style="cursor: default;" id="">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id=“1” class="sequence_div selectable"> 1 </div>
        </td>

        <td>
            <div id=“2” class="sequence_div selectable"> 2 </div>
        </td>

        <td>
            <div id=“3” class="sequence_div selectable"> 3 </div>
        </td>

        <td>
            <div id=“4” class="sequence_div selectable"> 4 </div>
        </td>

        <td>
            <div id=“5” class="sequence_div selectable"> 5 </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the drag select bit, so I assume the select is done by `click` (or `mousedown`), but change the event to fit. The selected `td`s will have class `.selected`:

```
$('td').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    var sum = parseInt($('#sum').text()) || 0;
    var val = parseInt($(this).find('.sequence_div').text());
    if($(this).hasClass('selected'))
        $('#sum').text(sum + val);
    else
        $('#sum').text(sum - val);
});
```

If the `td`s only contain the div with numbers, you can omit the `.find('.sequence_div')` bit.

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/tb6tzcf4/)

**EDIT:**

```
$(document).mousedown(function() {
    $('td').bind('mouseover',function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        var sum = parseInt($('#sum').text()) || 0;
        var val = parseInt($(this).find('.sequence_div').text());
        $(this).hasClass('selected') ? $('#sum').text(sum+val) : $('#sum').text(sum-val);
    });
})
$(document).mouseup(function() {
    $('td').unbind('mouseover');
});
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/tb6tzcf4/1/)

**EDIT #2:**

If you want a new `mousedown` to trigger a new selection at the beginning of it you can have something like:

```
$(document).mousedown(function() {
    $('td').removeClass('selected');
    $('#sum').text(0);
    $('td').bind('mouseover',function(){
    //rest of the code
```

Probably though would be better to use `mousedown/up` on `table` than `document`.

Comment: Thank you, but nope, that's not what I need.  With the jsfiddle you provided, I have to click on each of the cells individually.  I would like to select them while I'm dragging the cursor over them while holding down the mouse button, analogous to holding down your mouse button and then using your mouse to select all the words in a sentence.

Comment: Alright, something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/tb6tzcf4/1/ ? Wasn't sure about unselecting, so assumed going over a `td` toggles the selection.

Comment: Quick question.  I make the first selection and it works great.  However, when I want to make another selection, I would like for the first selection to go away.  How would I correct that?

Comment: It depends on what triggers the new selection, a new `mousedown` perhaps? If so, at the beginning of each `mousedown` you unselect all `tds` and change `sum` back to 0. Will edit the answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt, pure JS, it uses a few ES5 methods so it might not works on older browsers:

```
var box = {};
var area = document.getElementById('area');
var sum = document.getElementById('sum');
var vals = [].slice
    .call(document.querySelectorAll('.sequence_div'))
    .map(function(node){ return {
        val: parseInt(node.textContent,10),
        box: node.getBoundingClientRect()
    }});

window.addEventListener('mousedown', function(evt){
    box.x = evt.clientX;
    box.y = evt.clientY;
});
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt){
    if(Object.keys(box).indexOf('x') !== -1){
        var rect = {
            t: Math.min(evt.clientY,box.y), 
            l: Math.min(evt.clientX,box.x),
            w: Math.abs(evt.clientX - box.x),
            h: Math.abs(evt.clientY - box.y)
        };
        area.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;' +
            'top:' + rect.t + 'px;left:'+ rect.l + 'px;' +
            'width:' + rect.w + 'px;height:' + rect.h + 'px;'              
        );
        sum.textContent = vals.filter(function(val){
            return val.box.top >= rect.t &&
               val.box.top + val.box.height <= rect.t + rect.h &&
               val.box.left >= rect.l &&
               val.box.left + val.box.width <= rect.l + rect.w;
        }).reduce(function(memo, val){
            return memo + val.val;
        },0);
    }
});
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(evt){
    area.removeAttribute('style');
    sum.textContent = 0;
    box = {};
});
```

Working [demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sandro_paganotti/zaszf1n4/1/)